# Entity Framework, Repository pattern and let statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Trying to implement a correct Repository pattern with Entity Framework, I'm stumbling over some issues with let statements. What I want to do is:

```
var customer = (from cus in Customers.GetAll()
                let brokerExists = InsuredBrokers.GetAll().Any(ib => ib.INS_Id == cus.INS_Id)
            // ... more stuff
```

But this will give me an error

> **System.NotSupportedException:** 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
>   method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[*SNIP*.DataModel.EA_INB_InsuredBrokers_TB]
>   GetAll()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.'

What I instead can do is:

```
var customer = (from cus in Customers.GetAll()
            let brokerExists = _context.Set<EA_INB_InsuredBrokers_TB>().Any(ib => ib.INS_Id == cus.INS_Id)
            // ... more stuff
```

However, this breaks any point in using the Repository pattern. When I search for answers, people say to put it in a query on its own and reference it from memory, but since I actually have the customer's Id (`INS_Id`) in the let statement, I cannot do that.

`GetAll()` is like:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Set<T>().AsQueryable();
}
```

Are there any clever ways to get around this?

Comment: Is `Customers` the instance of your repository?

Comment: Also, can we have the full query? Is that possible? Currently, it's impossible to really help you fully because you only show parts of your code, and then have a `// more stuff` thingy.

Comment: Does this repository layer really give you any benefit or does it only restrict you? Ask yourself the question if you can do without. Also, is there a navigation property from Customer to Broker?

Comment: By the way I agree with Gert - many questions on SO ask about using repositories with EF, but I still have no idea why. EF context _already_ implements repository pattern - I don't get why you need one more repository on top of that.

Comment: @GertArnold and Evk I will take those concerns into account. I do agree that most repositories don't add very much over the genericrepository, and perhaps using DbSet<T> would be sufficient. I have to admit that I'm pretty new to the pattern.

Comment: The reason I ask about the navigation property is that it would make querying much easier, and independent of repository implementations. Something like `let brokerExists = cus.Broker != null` or `let brokerExists = cus.Brokers.Any()`.

Comment: @GertArnold You are right. But we have taken over a database that originates from the 90's. Foreign keys are pretty rare, and I'm not sure if I will ever be allowed to add any. But perhaps I could put them in EF-side only...

Comment: I'd certainly do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move `InsuredBrokers.GetAll()` out of the query:

```
var allBrokers = InsuredBrokers.GetAll();
var customer = (from cus in Customers.GetAll()
            let brokerExists = allBrokers.Any(ib => ib.INS_Id == cus.INS_Id)
        // ... more stuff
```

Then it will work fine. Since `GetAll` returns `IQueryable` and you don't enumerate it - this has no negative effect and there will still be one query to database, just like in your example with `_context`.

The reason is `let` statement is compiled like this:

```
Customers.GetAll().Select(cus => new {cus, brokerExists = InsuredBrokers.GetAll().Any(ib => ib.INS_Id == cus.INS_Id)}
```

Which means your call to `InsuredBrokers.GetAll()` is part of expression tree (it's inside `Select` expression), and entity framework cannot (will not) just call it to obtain value. It will try to translate it to SQL query, but has no idea what to do with `GetAll` method.

Comment: Of course you are correct. And it's a very simple solution. A little bit uglier to need to have it outside, but I'm going to guess that there is no better way to do it.

Comment: @SamiHuutoniemi I've added a bit of explanation about why it works like this.

Comment: But considering, that we can split it up by creating the query outside, one could think that LINQ To Entities could be smart enough to handle it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are wondering why you can use `_context.Set` inside the expression tree but not `InsuredBrokers.GetAll()`, EF has special processing (recognizes) the `DbContext` rooted expressions. The whole expression translation process is based on knowledge, and the user defined methods are not known, thus unsupported.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are trying to do a left join.

Your query:

```
var query = from customer in Customers
             join broker in InsuredBrokers
             on customer.InsertId equals broker.InsertId
             into resutGroups
            select new { Name = broker.Name, InsertId= broker.InsertId};
```

If you need entries for no maches use [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can refer to [this](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/03/25/inner-outer-lets-all-join-together-with-linq.aspx) for more on the same.

Comment: This is a completely different query.